# Calculating surface area above a certain point on a mountain or calculating surface area above a certain elevation

Tags: qgis

I have a station point somewhere (hydrostation) on a mountain, I need to calculate the complete surface area/Landmass of the mountain above this station point.

There are approximately 50-70 station points.

Comment: you'd need elevation data for the area you're in at an appropriate resolution (cell size) for your analysis... where are ya and who keeps digital elevation models (DEM's) for your area? Contours would also work... Regardless you can process the data and pick out the areas above the elevation and calculate the area (down to the appropriate resolution / cell size above)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is just half-answer, as I couldn't really get Upslope area to work on my machine to verify it. Hopefully you can make it work on yours.

You'll need QGIS with SAGA modules present in Processing, you'll also need DEM.

1. Go to `SAGA -> Terrain analysis - Hydrology -> Upslope area`. [This tool](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_hydrology_4.html) estimates flow to your station from around and gives you percentage of flow from each cell to the target. To run it, you need hydrologically correct DEM and X,Y for your target (station). You might need to fill sinks to produce correct DEM.
2. After getting upslope area you need to recalculate the result to binary. This can be done with Raster calculator, supposedly with simple 'more than 0' threshold.
3. Now you only need to count number of cells and multiply it by resolution. This is how you get the area that is upslope from your point.

As for the batch, right click on the tool in Processing and select Execute as batch process. You might need to set up a model or write a simple python script to automate it better.